# No return statement but not returning None?

Tags: python, function, return, nonetype

Not really understanding the `return` statement.

```
def func():
    print("test")
print(func())
```

As expected, this gives:

```
test
None
```

because `func()` is executed and "test" is printed. Also, since there is no `return` statement, `None` value is returned.

However, in this code, when I remove the outer `print` statement:

```
def func():
    print("test")
func()
```

gives only:
`test`

Here is where I don't understand. I read that by default, all functions return `None` value. If there is no `return` statement, then you will get `None`. However, in both pieces of codes, I do not have the `return` statement. Why doesn't the second code give `None` value as well?

Comment: In the first case you have 2 print calls. You get 2 lines in the output. In the second case, you have only one print call. And you get only one line of output. Has nothing to do with `return`. The function still returns `None` - you just don't `print` it.

Comment: becayse you don't print the function. Imagine storing the function in a variable. That var wouldn't have None

Comment: I just thought about a possibility that I watched from a video. It says that in the first code, `func()` is executed, giving "test" and "None"(because there is no `return` statement). Both values are passed to the outer `print` statement as arguments. Since the outer `print` statement only registers the "test" value as valid, then it thus prints "test" and "None". Since the second code does not have an outer `print` statement, "None" is not evaluated and thus not printed out? Is this logic correct?

Comment: Oh, so when they say functions will return None, I have to print None out to see it? Returning None doesn't mean None being shown on the output terminal?

Comment: Well a function without a return statement default to return `None` , but that does not mean it will print to standard input/output , but when you explicitly try to print that output of that function , it will print `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Oh, so when they say functions will return None, I have to print None out to see it? Returning None doesn't mean None being shown on the output terminal?

Correct.